# Why is it when is calling another function it the list not modify?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, function

I try to reverse the list with string when I'm calling it from function through function and it doesn't work somewhat

```
>>>
change_list = lambda lst_chn: lst_chn[::-1]

def check(lst_chk):
    change_list(lst_chk)
    return lst_chk

print(check([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
print(check(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']))
<<<
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

But when I do it using only one function it works pretty well.

```
>>>
print_list = lambda lst: lst[::-1]

lst_int = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst_str = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']

print(print_list(lst_int))
print(print_list(lst_str))
<<<
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
['8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're dumping the result and returning the original unmodified sequence:

```
def check(lst_chk):
    change_list(lst_chk)  # reversed sequence is discarded
    return lst_chk
```

In the second case, you return the reversed sequence and `print` it.

`[::-1]` *doesn't* operate in place, it returns its result, `lst_chk` is exactly the same after `change_list` is invoked.

You can either return the reversed sequence:

```
def check(lst_chk):
    return change_list(lst_chk)
```

to achieve a similar effect to your second case or, if you're always working with `list`s, use `reverse` which operates in-place.